# Pandas pivoting with boolean

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to learn how to create a path and rearranged and pivoting the data in  such a way. 
My sample data which i am doing practice looks like this.

```
ID  Time     Latitude  Longitude            
1   2:00    60.092033  20.765083                 
1   3:00    60.097300  20.672767                 
1   4:00    60.125550  20.593650                 
1   5:00    60.115233  20.505367                  
1   6:00    60.103800  20.425850                  
1   7:00    60.113750  20.335717                  
1   8:00    60.115683  20.303683                  
1   9:00    60.114817  20.305500                 
1   10:00   60.077983  20.316917                  
1   11:00   60.034500  20.305317
```

These are Latitude and longitude of a object in a given time. I have a couple of target coordinates which I want to check if that object is within those target coordinates. I am using of radius of 2 km and if the object is within than 2km, then I want to pivot from starting coordinates to the current coordinates and make it like a path. And the second pivoting starts right after the First pivoting ended.

I am using haversine libray to calculate the distance (km) between two different coordinates.

```
lat = df['Latitude'].values
long = df['Longitude'].values
CurrentCoordinates = zip(lat, long)
TargetedCoordinates = [60.103900, 20.415850]

for i, j in CurrentCoordinates
    print(haversine((i, j), TargetedCoordinates))
```

this gives me all the distance between each current coodinates and target coordinates.

Any kind of suggestions would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the example of desired output?

Comment: @zipa desire output is somewhat looks like which was given in accepted answer below. And for extra computation, I am going try to use networkx as suggested in the answer below. But if you happen to know, some simple way, I would be happy to try those one too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare each coordinate in the original dataframe with each target coordinate and get a dataframe of indicators true if the respective distance is under 2 km.

Here is one approach. The key ingredient is `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` that can compute pairwise distances.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from haversine import haversine

df = pd.read_csv(
    pd.compat.StringIO(
        """ID  Time     Latitude  Longitude
1   2:00    60.092033  20.765083
1   3:00    60.097300  20.672767
1   4:00    60.125550  20.593650
1   5:00    60.115233  20.505367
1   6:00    60.103800  20.425850
1   7:00    60.113750  20.335717
1   8:00    60.115683  20.303683
1   9:00    60.114817  20.305500
1   10:00   60.077983  20.316917
1   11:00   60.034500  20.305317"""
    ),
    sep=r" +",
)

targets = pd.DataFrame(
    [[60.103900, 20.415850], [60.403900, 20.715850]], columns=["Latitude", "Longitude"]
)

res_data = (
    cdist(
        df[["Latitude", "Longitude"]],
        targets[["Latitude", "Longitude"]],
        metric=haversine,
    )
    < 2
)

res_df = pd.DataFrame(
    res_data,
    index=df[["Latitude", "Longitude"]].round(3).apply(tuple, axis=1),
    columns=targets[["Latitude", "Longitude"]].round(3).apply(tuple, axis=1),
)
```

---

Result:

```
                  (60.104, 20.416)  (60.404, 20.716)
(60.092, 20.765)             False             False
(60.097, 20.673)             False             False
(60.126, 20.594)             False             False
(60.115, 20.505)             False             False
(60.104, 20.426)              True             False
(60.114, 20.336)             False             False
(60.116, 20.304)             False             False
(60.115, 20.306)             False             False
(60.078, 20.317)             False             False
(60.034, 20.305)             False             False
```

Comment: Thank you, this is somewhat I want to achieve. One more questions, How do I pivot from coordinates `60.092, 20.765) `  to `(60.104, 20.426)`  because it has reached the target coordinates (True). For the next pivoting, i want from  this coordinates `(60.114, 20.336)` to some next coordinates when it becomes true and the this continues, until all the coordinates are checked. :)

Comment: I see. You should probably add this more clearly to the body of your question; will get back to you in a sec. Also, are you always going to consider df points in order?

Comment: yes, location coordinates are always in order and can be repeated as object can go back to previous position and the pivoting is done from the current position ( which was on the target coordinates) and the next position ( which is also in the target coordinates) and this continues until all coordinates are checked :). Thank you again

Comment: Looks like you can do the computation in one go by appending the original target to your `df`, and running `cdist(df, df, metric=...)`. Other than that, if you want to recover paths from adjacency matrices, you may want to take a look at the `networkx` package.